# Dynamic scope for accessing Model Attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, activemodel

I'm currently using the mass assignment security baked into rails 3 to scope what level of users can update about their model.  For example this code allows me to protect attributes based on the user level.

```
  class Customer
    attr_accessor :name, :credit_rating

    attr_accessible :name
    attr_accessible :name, :credit_rating, :as => :admin
  end
```

I would like to be able to use this same idea for which attributes appear when I do a find.  For example I would like to be able to say

```
Customer.all.as(:admin)
```

and get back the credit rating.  Compare this to doing

```
Customer.all
```

and getting back all the attributes except the credit_rating

Is this something rails supports and I've missed?

Answer (score 0):

attr_accessible is used to filter incoming attributes on mass assignment. This is a convenience method created so that a developer does not need to manually clean the incoming hash of params, something he does not control.

When displaying information a developer is in full control of what he/she desires to show, so there seems to be no reason to limit the read functionality.

However, rails allows you to "select" the attributes you desire in a query: see http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#selecting-specific-fields

You could easily create a scope with the name admin that would limit the selected values.

If you do not desire to have the full models, but only the values, you could use the generated sql. e:g.

```
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_values(Customer.select('name').to_sql)
```

Comment: Named scope is a great idea!  It seems like a duplication of effort thought to say here are attributes writable as a user then give a list and then create a scope and say here are the attributes readable as user and give the same list.  Any ideas there?  Thanks for your response.  --Nick

Comment: Again, attr_accessible is a safety build to protect your model (layer) from tampered mass assignment. Displaying data is completely in your control in the view layer, thus there is no model level security needed for this.

Comment: Bert- great thoughts and I'm thinking about what you've said.  Here's my concern: I have scope :as_public, select('id, product, price') and attr_accessible :id, :product, :price, :as => :public and I'm worried about that data duplication.

Comment: If you define your scope after the attr_accessible you should be able to get the accessible attributes via the accessible_attributes(:public) method. I don't know the exact inner working of it, but it should not be to hard to get it from this point. But, once more, I don't think it's needed to do the restriction of your select, you can easily control data shown in your view layer.

Comment: Bert, thanks again for your advice. My view layer is a little tricky as I'm serving out json only. Thanks!